# How to make my Nikon D7000 stop adjusting to different lighting

Tags: lighting, nikon-d7000, video, backlight, auto-exposure-lock

I'm trying to film something with my Nikon D7000.

But when I hold it up to the subjects face/body, it starts to focus on the background and makes the the subject into a dark silhouette.

How do I maintain the correct lighting on my subject regardless of where he walks or the lighting around him/her?

Comment: While metering and exposure are concepts shared by photography and video, it looks like the particulars of locking exposure in this question are primarily concerned with video and might be addressed differently for photography.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "auto exposure lock" - which is the button marked "AE-L" on the back of your camera - whenever your subject starts to move somewhere that could cause a change in exposure.

This video explains how to use exposure locking on the D7000 - [Nikon D7000 Tutorial: Using the exposure lock setting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RQHxO75F7FY).

Answer (score 0):

Auto exposure/focus lock is how you stop it if you insist on being in one of the Auto modes, the other option is put the camera into M manual, and setup it how you want for the shot and it will remain how you set it.

Answer (score 0):

Use manual mode and set your shutter speed and aperture to expose the scene well. It won't change any of the parameters there on.